# how to run a vb script without user intreaction in a LAN?

Tags: vbscript

I have a group of network all connected in LAN and all are in domain. And I have a VB script to get the installed software. I have to run the script on all the systems without user interaction.

Comment: How are you getting installed software and why does that currently need user interaction? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WMIService in vbs, then try below with replacing **strComputer** in a loop, then another loop for the softwares

```
Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colSoftware = oWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Product")
```

But you have to run this with domain admin account or an account that is "Administrators" on all the domain PC.